# Ag-GRID with Angular : rendering issue

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-5, ag-grid

I try to put an ag-grid table in my angular 12 / bootstrap 5 application but I have a strange issue : the table is 0px height at render-time.

here is the rendered table :

[rendered table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GINCq.png)

by using the debug tool of chrome I can see that the following div is calculated with 0px height:
div class="ag-tab-guard ag-tab-guard-top" role="presentation" tabindex="0"

The table is in a bootstrap container directly under the body, here is the HTML of my component :

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <ag-grid-angular (cellClicked)="onCellClicked($event)"
        (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
        [animateRows]="true"
        [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
        [defaultColDef]="defaultColDef"
        [rowData]="rowData$ | async"
        [rowSelection]="'multiple'"
        style="width: 100%; height: 100%"
    ></ag-grid-angular>
    <!--<router-outlet></router-outlet>-->
</div>
```

I tried with and withoud ag-gris SCSS imports, themes, none solved the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue, I was importins SCSS files of AG-GRID in my component SCSS, but it requires the files to be imported in the styles.scss

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).